# Index Sorted by Most Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, view

I'm having trouble with sorting an index of "pins" by most views. The view isn't showing any of the sorted "pins." When a user visits a pin, it stores the data in the 'visit_details' and 'visits' tables. In the model I have the functions to handle the sorting but I'm not sure if that is the problem or what's going on.

```
create_table "visit_details", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "visit_id"
  t.string   "ip_address", limit: 15
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "visit_details", ["ip_address"], name: "index_visit_details_on_ip_address"

create_table "visits", force: true do |t|
 t.integer  "total_visits"
 t.integer  "unique_visits"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.integer  "pin_id"
end

add_index "visits", ["pin_id"], name: "index_visits_on_pin_id"
```

My controller:

```
class PinMostViewsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @random_model = Pin.order('random()').first
  @pins = Pin.top_viewed(params[:page], params[:date])
 end

 def pin_most_views_params
  params.require(:pin).permit(:ip_address, :visit_id)
 end

end
```

My pin.rb model stores the logic:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

acts_as_commentable



has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300X300>", :thumb => "100X100>" }



validates :image, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
    validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg",      "image/png", "image/gif"] }

has_one :visit

  validates :team, presence: true
  validates :position, presence: true

def self.top_viewed(page, time_period)
case time_period
when "all_time"
  Pin.all_time(page)
when "year"
  Pin.order_most_viewed(page, 1.year.ago)
when "month"
  Pin.order_most_viewed(page, 1.month.ago)
when "week"
  Pin.order_most_viewed(page, 1.week.ago)
when "day"
  Pin.order_most_viewed(page, 1.day.ago)
  else
    Pin.all_time(page)
  end
 end

  def self.order_most_viewed(page, date)
  visits, ids = {}, []

  # Create a hash containing pins and their respective visit numbers
  VisitDetail.includes(:visit).where('created_at >= ?', date).each do |visit_detail|
  pin_id = visit_detail.visit.pin_id.to_s

  if visits.has_key?(pin_id)
    visits[pin_id] += 1
    else
    visits[pin_id] = 1
   end
  end

  if visits.blank?
  # Since no visits existed for this time period, we simply return an empty array
  # which will display no results on the view page
  []
  else
  # Now we sort the pins from most views to least views
  visits.sort_by{ |k,v| v }.reverse.each { |k, v| ids << k }

  # With our array of ids, we get all of the pins in the particular order
  Pin.page(page).per_page(30).where(id: ids).order_by_ids(ids)
 end
end

   # A nice query method that will sort by ids, used for the order_most_viewed class method  above
 def self.order_by_ids(ids)
  order_by = ["case"]

  ids.each_with_index.map do |id, index|
  order_by << "WHEN id='#{id}' THEN #{index}"
end

order_by << "end"

 order(order_by.join(" "))
end

 def self.all_time(page)
    Pin.includes(:visit)
    .where('visits.id IS NOT NULL')
    .order("visits.total_visits DESC")
    .order("visits.total_visits > 0")
    .page(page).per_page(30)
 end


 # Instance Methods
 # ================
 def image_remote_url=(url_value)
   self.image = URI.parse(url_value) unless url_value.blank?
   super
 end

 def previous
  self.class.first(:conditions => ["id < ?", id], :order => "id desc")
 end

 def next
 self.class.first(:conditions => ["id > ?", id], :order => "id asc")
    end



end
```

And finally, my view (index of pins that are supposed to be sorted by most views)

```
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
   <div class="box panel panel-default">
    <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), pin %>
     <div class="panel-body">
    <p><%= pin.description %></p>
    <p><strong><%= pin.user.name if pin.user %></strong></p>

    <% if current_user && pin.user == current_user %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= link_to edit_pin_path(pin) do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
          Edit
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          Delete
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

   </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for using `case` / `switch` ;)

Comment: Have you tried to probe the model in the console? Fire it up and try out your model methods, particularly `Pin.top_viewed(..)`. Try different values, see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment yet. Did try tracing it?
You can use  `p` right in the html to see what's going on there.
Also you can use logger.info in controller side.
Thus you will see, where you problem is hiding. When you see `nil` or `[]`